# Moving /tmp to a different mounted drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, mysql

I've mapped my MySQL datadir to a different (and bigger) disk with 900GB

```
[root@web ~]# df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/xvda1       40G   24G   14G  64% /
    tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev/shm
    /dev/xvdb1      886G  658G  184G  79% /mnt/cbsvolume1
```

The /tmp is located in the smaller 40GB disk

```
[root@web ~]# df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       40G   24G   14G  64% /
```

It appears MySQL is using the /tmp directory and because of that I'm running sometimes out of disk space when trying to perform big MySQL operations.

How can I change the `/tmp` to also use the bigger disk?

Comment: It looks to me like your `/tmp` isn't even located on a disk.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I have a strong feeling you're right, but not sure what you mean :) Can you elaborate?

Comment: [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) is mounted in volatile memory. Meaning it resides in your RAM, not on your hard drive. That's why the contents are gone after you reboot your machine. That being said, I misread the output you posted in your question. I imagined `/tmp` to be `tmpfs`, which isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Change the TMPDIR environmental variable to a filesystem/directory with more disk space.

Edit the local configuration file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/local.cnf`. This file contains your local changes - and will not be overwritten if you upgrade mysql. Note the config files may be stored in a different location - use find to locate the default config file my.cnf. Usually local.cnf would be kept in the same directory.

```
sudo find / -name my.cnf     # look for path of config files
```

Edit local.cnf e.g.  `sudo vi /etc/mysql/conf.d/local.cnf`

Add these lines to local.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir = /your/newpath
```

Then re-start mysql.

From the [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html) documentation:

> **B.5.4.4 Where MySQL Stores Temporary Files**
>
> On Unix, MySQL uses the value of the TMPDIR environment variable as
>   the path name of the directory in which to store temporary files. If
>   TMPDIR is not set, MySQL uses the system default, which is usually
>   /tmp, /var/tmp, or /usr/tmp.

Comment: Can you show best way to change and if should I stop mysql before?

Comment: See edited answer. You don't need to stop mysql before making the changes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit confused as to the difference between this and the `export TMPDIR=<path>` suggestion. Also, I don't have a `/etc/mysql/` directory, might it be located in a different place?

Comment: I don't recommend using export - unless you plan to start mysql from the same shell that issued the `export` command. Use `find` as explained in edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the contents of `/tmp` are deleted on reboot.

However, in your case, you could try changing/adding `TMPDIR` environment variable in:

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/local.cnf
```

Comment: Did that, `df -h /tmp` still shows the same thing. How can I verify it 'worked'?

Comment: Cool. And is this setting temporary till reboot? Can I add this line to some sort of booting script and make it permanent? (btw I also believe /tmp is deleted on reboot, mysql only uses it for temporary tables and such)

Comment: I actually tried that, but still mysql uses the `/tmp` from the smaller mount. Also, I don't have a directory `/etc/mysql/` might it be in a different place?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location (you can use `my.cnf` file as well)

Comment: The `my.cnf` is actually under `/etc`. I actually tried writing there `tmpdir = /mnt/cbsvolume1/var/tmp` but after that the mysql didn't want to start.

Comment: @Noam Did you also write [mysqld]? See [suspectus](http://superuser.com/a/769791/334004)' answer.

Comment: Yes. I actually see the error I'm getting is: `/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/mnt/cbsvolume1/newTmpDir/ibvxXVDh' (Errcode: 13)` So I guess I need to add premissions to that directory? So I also did `chown mysql:mysql /mnt/cbsvolume1/newTmpDir` and it seems to be working. Thanks!